# jQuery datatables - difference between fnGetNodes() and fnGetData()?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I was wondering what the difference is between these two calls?  fnGetNodes() returns all rows and so does fnGetData().  What is the difference then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fnGetNodes()` returns a list of `tr` elements that have been generated.  If you are using `deferRender: true` fnGetNodes() **will only return rows from pages that have been visited.**

`fnGetData()` on the other hand returns the array of objects `aoData` that contains all rows of data (but not the tr elements).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

This is what we should do to access all rows using fnGetNodes()

```
var rows = $("#myTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

Using fnGetData()

```
$('#table1').dataTable.fnGetData();
```

I think it's more of functionality where specific and complex row and column operations can be done using fnGetNodes and for more generic operations fnGetData is used.