# Does not count all rows with fnGetNodes()

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have following table initialization code

```
var myTable = $jq11('#myTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": someUrl,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0, 6, 7] }
    ],
    "columns": [
        { 
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
   // "deferRender": true,
    "dom": 'l<"#removeButtonDiv.removeButton">rtip',
    "filter": false,
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $('#removeButtonDiv').html('<input id="removeButton" type="button" value="Remove"  style="float:right; height: 25px;" disabled />');
    },
    "lengthMenu": [ [20, 40, 60, 80, 100], [20, 40, 60, 80, 100] ],
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "No data to list",
        "infoFiltered": " "
    },
    "order": [[4, "desc"]],
    "processing": true,
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        $.each(selected, function(index, value){
            $('#'+value).attr("checked", "checked");
        });
    },
    "serverSide": true
    //,"sPaginationType": "input"
});
```

but

```
alert($(myTable.fnGetNodes()).length);
```

always shows 20 which is my page size. since I have 5 pages full records. Isn't it suppose to show 100. Let me know if I am missing anything about this api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge with datatables is not very big but upon reading the API and finding [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685522/jquery-datatables-difference-between-fngetnodes-and-fngetdata) and some info from [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19560/fngetnodes-which-is-it-all-rows-or-current-table) I came to the conclusion that depending on the settings you are using `fnGetNodes()` acts differently.

Since the table is being processed server-side, `.fnGetNodes()` will only get the *currently generated elements*. Datatables does not seem to have a direct way to get all the rows with server-side processing, since the server returns only the *currently requested rows*.

---

If you're only looking to count them, the returned ajax response however should contain the total number of rows https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data

```
var myTable = $jq11('#myTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
       "url": someUrl,
       "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
          console.log('Total : ' + json.recordsTotal.length);
          return json;
        }
     },
     /* ... */
});
```

Comment: May be you are right. I didn't think about it. Having said that I wonder how I can implement my plan now. I was planning to change CSS of rows(which can be on different page) depending upon the operation status response from the server. Like keep check box selected for rows which aren't removed successfully.

Comment: I think this may help with that https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html I don't know the full complexity of what you want to do, but you will have to save the state of the rows client-side somehow like creating an object where you store and delete selected rows or properties

Answer (score 0):

```
use the fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() of the datatable. 
example : http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2401/record-count-with-server-side-processing
```

I have used it before and I think I could give you a snippet:

```
var table = $('#table ').DataTable(
{
                        "dom" : 'rtp', // Initiate drag column
                        "fnDraw" : false,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax" : ... ...
                            }
                        }),
                      "fnDrawCallback" : drawCallBack,
});

function drawCallBack() {
    console.log(this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
}
```

check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ns7mt3La/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all rows then use below:

1. `this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal()` in your callback method.
2. `fnGetNodes()` will give all rows inside `tbody` tag but if you want to count using `fnGetNodes()` then use like this:

   ```
   this.fnGetNodes().length  //will count all rows
   ```